# Error - this S4 class is not subsettable

Tags: r

I know there are several answers on this question, however I could not find any applicable to my question. Could anyone help me in regards to the error this S4 class is not subsettable at the bottom of this code. I am not sure where this error comes from. The output result should be the thresholded coefficients of DWT.

```
xx <- list(list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3,2,4,3,2,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,3,3),
         c(0,3,1,4,1,2,7,5,4,1,3,4,9,2,7,5,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,5,1,3,1)),
      list(c(0,3,1,4,1,2,7,5,4,1,3,4,9,2,2,4,7,6,4,2,1,1,1,5,1,3,1),
         c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,1,2,3,5,4,3,3)),
      list(c(0,3,1,4,1,2,7,5,4,1,3,4,3,2,2,4,7,6,4,2,1,1,1,5,1,3,1),
         c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,3,2,3,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,1,2,3,5,4,3,3)))

# Select Filter.  
library(wavelets)
filter <- c    ("d2","d4","d6", "c6","d8","la8","la10","d12","c12","la12","la14","d14","d16","la16","d18","c18","la18") 
boundary <- c("periodic","reflection")
g <- seq(1:length(xx))
fun <- function (x) seq(1: as.integer (floor (logb ((length(xx[[x]][[1]])),base=2))))   
nlevel <- lapply( g,fun)
fun <-  function(x) expand.grid(filter=filter,nlevel=nlevel[[x]],boundary=boundary, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
w3<- lapply(g,fun)
z <- c(seq(1:length(w3)))                                                
mapply3 <- function(i) {
w4 <- w3[[i]]
mapply ( function ( m,k,p,x ) modwt ( x, filter = m, n.levels = k, boundary=p) , w3[[i]]$filter, w3[[i]]$nlevel, w3[[i]]$boundary , MoreArgs = list(x = (xx[[i]][[1]])) )
}
DWT <- lapply ( z, mapply3 )

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
vscale <-  c("level")
# smooth.levels  <-  c(nlevel)
prior <- c("laplace")
a  <-  c(0.1,0.3) 
bayesfac  <-  c("TRUE")
threshrule  <-  c("median","mean")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

X <-   seq(1:length(DWT))
fun <-   function (x) DWT[x]
u  <-   lapply(X,fun)
fun <-   function (x) seq(1:length(DWT[[x]]))
U <-   lapply(X,fun)
L1   <-   expand.grid (  vscale = vscale, prior = prior, a = a , bayesfac = bayesfac , threshrule = threshrule , stringsAsFactors = FALSE  )
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------   
library ( EbayesThresh )
mapply2  <- function ( DWTi , LL )                                                                                                  {
mapply (  function ( c,e,f,g,h,x ) ebayesthresh.wavelet ( x, vscale = c, prior = e, a = f, bayesfac = g, threshrule = h ) , LL$vscale , LL$prior , LL$a , LL$bayesfac , LL$threshrule , MoreArgs  =   list  (  x   =   DWTi )  )
} 
mapply3 <-  function(  i, L1, DWT  )  {  
DWTi      <-   DWT      [[i]][U[[i]]]         
w3          <-   L1 
lapply( DWTi, mapply2, w3 )    
} 
M1 <-   lapply(z, mapply3, L1, DWT) 
# Error in x.dwt[[j]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

Comment: This code doesn't run: there is no `g` (line 6).

Comment: @jlhoward, appologies corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in the "wavelets" package. I looked up the source code of `ebayesthresh.wavelet`, copied it, and added some "print" debugging:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The same as "ebayesthresh.wavelet.dwt" plus some "print" for debugging:

ebayesthresh.wvlt.dwt <-
function (x.dwt, vscale = "independent", smooth.levels = Inf, 
          prior = "laplace", a = 0.5, bayesfac = FALSE, threshrule = "median") 
{
  nlevs <- length(x.dwt) - 1
  slevs <- min(nlevs, smooth.levels)

print("nlevs:")
print(nlevs)
print("slevs")
print(slevs)

  if (is.character(vscale)) {
    vs <- substring(vscale, 1, 1)
    if (vs == "i") 
      vscale <- mad(x.dwt[[1]])
    if (vs == "l") 
      vscale <- NA
  }

print("1:slevs:")
print(1:slevs)

  for (j in 1:slevs) {

print("j:")    
print(j)

    x.dwt[[j]] <- ebayesthresh(x.dwt[[j]], prior, a, bayesfac, 
                               vscale, FALSE, threshrule)
print("OK")
  }
  return(x.dwt)
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The same as "ebayesthresh.wavelet",
# but it calls "ebayesthresh.wvlt.dwt" instead of "ebayesthresh.wavelet.dwt":

ebayesthresh.wvlt <-
function (xtr, vscale = "independent", smooth.levels = Inf, prior = "laplace", 
          a = 0.5, bayesfac = FALSE, threshrule = "median") 
{
  xcl <<- class(xtr)
  if (class(xcl) == "dwt " && length(xcl) > 1) {
    xtr <- ebayesthresh.wavelet.splus(xtr, vscale, smooth.levels, 
                                      prior, a, bayesfac, threshrule)
    return(xtr)
  }
  if (xcl == "wd") {
    xtr <- ebayesthresh.wavelet.wd(xtr, vscale, smooth.levels, 
                                   prior, a, bayesfac, threshrule)
    return(xtr)
  }
  if (xcl == "dwt" || xcl == "modwt") {
    xtr <- ebayesthresh.wvlt.dwt(xtr, vscale, smooth.levels, 
                                    prior, a, bayesfac, threshrule)
    return(xtr)
  }
  print("Unknown wavelet transform type; no smoothing performed")
  return(xtr)
}
```

The function `mapply2` now calls `ebayesthresh.wvlt` instead of `ebayesthresh.wavelet`:

```
mapply2  <- function ( DWTi , LL )                                                                                                  
{
  mapply (  function ( c,e,f,g,h,x ) ebayesthresh.wvlt ( x, 
                                                         vscale = c, 
                                                         prior = e, 
                                                         a = f, 
                                                         bayesfac = g, 
                                                         threshrule = h ) , 
            LL$vscale , 
            LL$prior , 
            LL$a , 
            LL$bayesfac , 
            LL$threshrule, 
            list(x=DWTi )  )
}
```

Let's see:

```
> M1 <-   lapply(z, mapply3, L1, DWT) 
[1] "nlevs:"
[1] 0
[1] "slevs"
[1] 0
[1] "1:slevs:"
[1] 1 0
[1] "j:"
[1] 1
Error in x.dwt[[j]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
>
```

In R the `for`-loop

```
for (j in 1:n) {...}
```

is ***not empty,*** if `n` is 0 or negative. (Another reason to avoid `for`-loops?) `j` runs from 1 to `n` in steps of -1. A similar bug I found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098948/time-series-of-length-0-from-the-timeseries-package-has-dubious-timestamps)

If we replace the `for`-loop in `ebayesthresh.wvlt.dwt` by a `while`-loop, the error message disappears:

```
  j <- 1

  while (j<=slevs) {
    x.dwt[[j]] <- ebayesthresh(x.dwt[[j]], prior, a, bayesfac, 
                               vscale, FALSE, threshrule)
    j <- j+1
  }
```

Comment: I dont follow the bug solution. It seems not to have relation to the question as per there are several variables in the question that go into DWT above. Nor is M1 a solution, M1 should yield a list of the thresholded coeficients not the list that results from your solution.  Usually the S4 solution concerns the class of object which I believe has a relation in this case to the last part of the code, I think the DWT portion and the subsetting of the individual elements. There may be a bug I dont know but however I dont think is relevant to the question or the solution. Many thanks

Comment: The error occurs in `M1 <-   lapply(z, mapply3, L1, DWT)`: `mapply3` calls `mapply2`, `mapply2` calls `ebayesthresh.wavelet`, `ebayesthresh.wavelet` calls `ebayesthresh.wavelet.dwt`, and then it happens. My answer shows the traceback to the point where the error message comes from. All I did was the replacement of `ebayesthresh.wavelet` and `ebayesthresh.wavelet` by `ebayesthresh.wvlt` and `ebayesthresh.wvlt.dwt`, respectively. Your question was where the error message comes from. So my answer is very well related to your question.

Comment: Because of the error "this S4 class is not subsettable", so far you haven't been able to check if `M1` yields what you have expected. If now you see that this is not the case, the reason is something that is really not related to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I understand and it may be the case as per your explanation, however, how do I know that this is correct when the variables you use for the function ebayesthresh.wvlt.dwt and ebayesthresh.wvlt are not those stated in the question or you include a variable that is not included in my example. On another hand you use a different code than the one in the example and dont use a apply family function which is necesary as there are multiple variables. It is my impression as per the above explanation that you are solving a different problem.

Comment: I did use the same code as you. As I mentioned earlier, I didn't do anything else but replacing `ebayesthresh.wavelet` and `ebayesthresh.wavelet` by `ebayesthresh.wvlt` and `ebayesthresh.wvlt.dwt` for purpose of debugging. The only difference between `....wavelet` and `...wvlt` are the additional "print" statements. In my answer I didn't show the parts of the code that are identical to the code shown in the question. But I used the same `mapply` functions. Only `ebayesthresh.wavelet` had to be replaced by `ebayesthresh.wvlt` in `mapply2`, as shown in my answer.

Comment: I guess you are confused about `vscale = "independent"` in the argument list of `ebayesthresh.wvlt`, for example. Here "indepentent" is NOT the value that is used for `vscale` in our case. `vscale` is an optional argument of the functions `ebayesthresh.wvlt` and `ebayesthresh.wavelet`. If the function is called without a value for the argument `vscale`, the default value "independent" is used. The same applies to `smooth.levels = Inf` and so on. If you don't believe it, look up the source code of `ebayesthresh.wavelet`. Just type `ebayesthresh.wavelet` (without `()`) on the console,

Comment: Thanks, for this specific example the outcome is the thresholded coeficcients of the wavelet DWT. My expresson works fine for other functions with non dwt or modwt objects. So you are right in that the issue is most likely the mentioned bug as it becomes difficult to suset DWT. Now the question is how would you go with having a and threshole variables having two values each instead than one and the expression providing the thresholded coefficients.

Comment: What do you mean by "two values instead of one"? In `mapply2` the function `ebayesthresh.wavelet` is called once for each point in the grid `LL`. In `LL` there are two `a`-values, 0.1 and 0.3. So `ebayesthresh.wavelet` is called with two values for `a`. But not both values at once. Each time `ebayesthresh.wavelet` is called, its argument `a` is either 0.1 or 0.3, and both values occur.

Comment: No I understand however when I apply your proposed solution at the end it does not work nor it gives the desired DWT values thersholded.

Comment: Your question was where the error message comes from. If the code gives the desired result or not is another question, which we can't discuss here. StackOverflow is already complaining about the number of comments. You should ask yourself if the question about the error message is answered or not. And please keep in mind that a correct answer is a good answer that deserves some credit, even if it "only" shows that there is another problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "proposed solution at the end ... does not work"? Did you get an error message? If so, what was the error message you got?

Comment: Found the solution is an error in selecting the employed package. Many thanks

Comment: Doesn't my answer and our lengthy discussion deserve some credit? Please be fair.